# Finding a specific text in a page using selenium python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a specific text from a page https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.codein.filemanager&hl=en using selenium python. I'm looking for the element name - current version from the above url. I used the below code

```
 browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
 browser.get(sampleURL) # Load page

 elem = browser.find_elements_by_clsss_name("Current Version") # Find the query box
 print elem;
 time.sleep(2) # Let the page load, will be added to the API
 browser.close()
```

I don't seem to get the output printed. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: There is no element with the class of `Current Version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no class with name "Current Version". If you want to capture the version number that is below the "Current Version" text, the you can use this `xpath` expression:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@itemprop='softwareVersion']")
```